# NSLocalizedString sometimes returns the string other times shows the key

Tags: ios, objective-c

Using the same key sometimes returns the value othertimes it returns the key.

Code:

```
NSLog(@"%@ : %@", NSLocalizedString(@"TESTSTRING", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"TESTSTRING", nil));
```

Output in console:
\^PTESTSTRING : Test String

Here are the key and value from the Localizable.strings file.

```
"TESTSTRING" = "Test String";
```

I see no differences between both localisation macros but one gets the value the other not. Has anybody ever come across this?

What does the \^P before the key signify in the console output?

Thanks,
NSC

Comment: Maybe typo error or your device is running with different locale which doesn't have localization resource?

Comment: It returns the key when it can't find a value for it.

Comment: It returns the key if not value is found for it (key not available in the locale, etc.). Also, I'd say that you have an extra invisible char somewhere. Try by copy/pasting the key from the Localizable.strings file.

Comment: @RyanB  Guys I use the macro twice. Using the exact same key. It works once, then fails once in the same NSLog. See the code above and the console output.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you throw `/* No comment provided by engineer. */` above the line in Localizable.strings?